# Rendering text on canvas is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have something like this (also here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRa8c/)):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 300);

ctx.fillStlye = "white";
ctx.font = "16px Arial, sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText("asdf", 20, 20);
```

Now that code was supposed to paint "asdf" on the rectangle, but it isn't. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a typo in the code which prevents `fillStyle` from changing (and as you basically just adding a new property to ctx there won't be any error either):

```
ctx.fillStlye = "white";
          ^^
```

should be:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
```

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PRa8c/1/)**

Comment: ...And I was sitting on it for about half an hour wondering what the hell is wrong with this code... Thanks!

Comment: @ojek yeah, code blindness happens to us all from time to time :) Glad I could help.